# How to avoid using dynamic_cast, when implementing external actions?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

dynamic_cast is pure evil. Everybody knows it. Only noobs use dynamic_cast. :)

That's what I read about dynamic_cast. Many topics on stackoverflow say "use virtual functions in this case".

I've got some interfaces that reflect capabilities of objects. Let's say:

```
class IRotatable
{
  virtual void set_absolute_angle(float radians) =0;
  virtual void rotate_by(float radians) =0;
};

class IMovable
{
  virtual void set_position(Position) =0;
};
```

and a base for a set of classes that may implement them:

```
class Object
{
  virtual ~Object() {}
};
```

In GUI layer I would like to enable/disable or show/hide buttons depending on which features are implemented by the object selected by the user:

```
Object *selected_object;
```

I would do it in such a way (simplified):

```
button_that_rotates.enabled = (dynamic_cast<IRotatable*>(selected_object) != nullptr);

(...)

void execute_rotation(float angle)
{
  if(auto rotatable = dynamic_cast<IRotatable*>(selected_object))
  {
    rotatable->rotate_by(angle);
  }
}
```

but as other (more experienced ones) say, it is obvious evidence of bad design.

What would be a good design in this case?

And no, I don't want a bunch of virtual functions in my `Object`. I would like to be able to add new interface and new classes that implement it (and new buttons) without touching `Object`.

Also virtual function like `get_buttons` in by `Object` doesn't seem good for me. My `Object` knows completely nothing about GUI, buttons and such things.

A function like `get_type` that returns some enum could also solve a problem, but I don't see why self-implemented substitute of RTTI should be better than the native one (ok, it would be faster, but it doesn't matter in this case).

Comment: This will be a good question at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowing what `selected_object` is. On the surface, it doesn't look like you need casts at all.

Comment: I added some basic info on `selected_object`

Comment: The general way to avoid dynamic casting is to not throw away the type information in the first place. You might find the visitor pattern useful. For very tightly coupled classes it lets you avoid the casting entirely, and otherwise it lets you centralize the casting. But first and foremost think hard about how to change your design so as to avoid throwing away needed information. For example, instead of a big collection of everything, consider two or more collections that are more restricted and directly useful.

Comment: "dynamic_cast is pure evil". Well it's still the only way to check if a class implements a specific interface at runtime. A dynamic cast to _an interface_ isn't evil...

Answer (score 2):

You've already hit the nail on the head: you're trying to get type information from an "opaque" Object* type. Using dynamic_cast is just a hack to get there. Arguably your problem is actually that C++ doesn't have what you want: good type information. But here's some thoughts.

First, if you're going to a lot of this sort of thing, you may find that you are actually shifting away from typical inheritance and your program may be better suited to a component based design pattern, as is more common in video games. There you often have a somewhat opaque GameObject at the root and want to know what "components" it has. Unity does this sort of thing and they have nice editor windows based on components attached to the GameObject; but C# also has nice type info.

Second, some other part of the might know about the concrete type of the object and can help build your visual display, causing the Object* to no longer be a bottleneck.

Third, if you do go with something like the option you're talking about, I think you will find having type id of some sort vs. the use of dynamic_cast to be more helpful, since you can then build tables to look up types to say, visual builders.

Also, you were wondering why a self-rolled type info vs. RTTI? If you are quite concerned about performance, RTTI is on for all types and that means everything could take a hit; the self-rolled option allows for opt-in (at the cost of complexity). Additionally you won't need to push this onto others if you're writing a library pulled in via source, etc.